# How to pass SOAP headers into python SUDS that are not defined in WSDL file

Tags: python, xml, wsdl, suds, soapheader

I have a camera on my network which I am trying to connect to with suds but suds doesn't send all the information needed. I need to put extra soap headers not defined in the WSDL file so the camera can understand the message. All the headers are contained in a SOAP envelope and then the suds command should be in the body of the message.

I have checked the suds [website](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation)
and it says to pass in the headers like so: (This passes in the element as a header but I have an envelope so I'm not sure how to input this)

```
from suds.sax.element import Element
client = client(url)
ssnns = ('ssn', 'http://namespaces/sessionid')
ssn = Element('SessionID', ns=ssnns).setText('123')
client.set_options(soapheaders=ssn) 
result = client.service.addPerson(person)
```

Now, I am not sure how I would implement this. Say for example, I have the below header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:SOAP
ENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"
<wsa:MessageID SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="true">urn:uuid:43268c01-f09c6</wsa:MessageID>
 <SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

Using this or a similar example does anyone know how I would pass a valid SOAP message to the targeted service?

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have worked out how to enter in new headers and namespaces in suds.
As stated above you create an Element and pass it in as a soapheader as so:

```
from suds.sax.element import Element 
client = client(url) 
ssnns = ('ssn', 'http://namespaces/sessionid') 
ssn = Element('SessionID', ns=ssnns).setText('123') 
client.set_options(soapheaders=ssn)  
result = client.service.addPerson(person)
```

But if you would like to add a namespace I have found adding a prefix seem's to do the trick. So when you create one of the elements you add `addPrefix`. I'm not sure if this was the way it was intended to be done but it work's.

```
ssn = Element('SessionID', ns=ssnns).setText('123').addPrefix(p='SOAP-ENC', u='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding')
```

The `p = 'SOAP-ENC'` can be any prefix `eg. wsa` and the `u = http://address` is the address of the namespace.

A complete script that would run could be:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.6

import suds
#import logging
from suds.client import Client
from suds.sax.element import Element
from suds.sax.attribute import Attribute
from suds.xsd.sxbasic import Import

def absoluteMove():

    # connects to WSDL file and stores location in variable 'client'
    client = Client('http://10.10.10.10/p.wsdl')
    client.options.location = 'http://10.10.10.10:32963'

    # Create the header
    wsans = ('wsa', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing')
    mustAttribute = Attribute('SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand', 'true')
    n1s = ('SOAP-ENC', 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding')
    msgId = Element('Element').addPrefix(p='SOAP-ENC', u='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding')

    msgId2 = Element('Address', ns=wsans).setText('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous')
    msgId1 = Element('ReplyTo', ns=wsans).insert(msgId2)
    msgId1.append(mustAttribute)

    msgId3 = Element('To', ns=wsans).setText('http://10.10.10.10:32954')
    msgId3.append(mustAttribute)

    client.set_options(soapheaders=[msgId, msgId1, msgId3, msgId2])

    # Create 'token' object to pass as an argument using the 'factory' namespace
    token = client.factory.create('ns4:ReferenceToken')

    # Create 'dest' object to pass as an argument and values passed to this object
    dest = client.factory.create('ns4:PTZVector')
    dest.PanTilt._x=1
    dest.PanTilt._y=4.9
    dest.Zoom._x=1


    # Create 'speed' object to pass as an argument and values passed to this object
    speed = client.factory.create('ns4:PTZSpeed')
    speed.PanTilt._x=0
    speed.PanTilt._y=0
    speed.Zoom._x=1

    # 'AbsoluteMove' method invoked passing in the new values entered in the above objects

    try:
        result = client.service.AbsoluteMove(token, dest, speed)
        print "absoluteMove result ", result
        return result
    except suds.WebFault, e:
        print "suds.WebFaults caught: "
        print e

if __name__ == '__main__': result = absoluteMove()
```

This moves the camera. To change the type of soap-envelope check [my next question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544331/overwrite-the-soap-envelope-in-suds-python).

You can add logging into this script whci allow's you to check what xml command you have sent which is handy:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

The location can be put into the script as an option if the location is not in the wsdl file.