# Overwrite the Soap Envelope in Suds python

Tags: python, xml, soap, suds, envelope

I have a camera and I am trying to connect to it vis suds. I have tried to send raw xml and have found that the only thing stopping the xml suds from working is an incorrect Soap envelope namespace.

The envelope namespace is:

`xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"`

and I want to rewrite it to:

`xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"`

In order to add a namespace in python I try this code:

`message = Element('Element_name').addPrefix(p='SOAP-ENC', u='www.w3.org/ENC')`

But when I add the `SOAP-ENV` to the namespace it doesn't write as it is hardcoded into the suds bindings. Is there a way to overwrite this in suds?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What type of error do you get?Could you elaborate and post your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get this working, the soap envelope is hard coded into `bindings.py` that is stored in `suds.egg` installed in your site-packages. I changed the SOAP envelope address to `http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope`. This was compatible with my camera. I was unable to find a command to overwrite this envelope in suds so I hard coded it in to the bindings.py.

Thanks for any help

Comment: For how to enter header's into suds check out my previous question. I'll post my code as I know how little documentation there is.

Answer (score 6):

I got around it by manually overriding the `suds.binding.envns` variable in the `bindings` module:

```
from suds.bindings import binding
binding.envns=('SOAP-ENV', 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope')
```

From here on, all goes well (with *my* service, that is)

Answer (score 1):

Manually updating `binding.py` definitely isn't the right way to go. You should be able to utilize the `ImportDoctor` to override your default bindings.  Have a look at the documentation for [fixing broken schemas](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation#FIXINGBROKENSCHEMAs) on the Suds website.

Also, what versions of Python and suds are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.plugin import MessagePlugin

WSDL_url = "my_url?wsdl"

class MyPlugin(MessagePlugin):
    def marshalled(self, context):
        #print(str(context.envelope))
        context.envelope.nsprefixes['SOAP-ENV']='myText'

client = Client(WSDL_url, plugins=[MyPlugin()])
```

Comment: This answer should be considered. Thank you Nikola!