# change XML evelope settings in suds

Tags: python, web-services, api, soap, suds

I'm trying to acces a SOAP API. This works while using SOAP-UI as a test environment.
Now I want to implement it in Suds/Python. The actual request suds makes differs in the soap:Envelope element. I have no idea how to set it so it works.

The correct request made by SOAP-UI

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:plur="pluriform:works:datatypes:DagstatenApp-0">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      ...
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

with the rather minimal python code:

```
from suds.client import Client
client = Client(url)
client.set_options(soapheaders=(user, passwd)
result = client.service.getWhatEver(arg1, arg2)
```

I get this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="pluriform:works:datatypes:DagstatenApp-0" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
       <ns1:Body>
       ...
    </ns1:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Which if I copy-paste it in SOAP-UI. I get this error:

```
<soapenv12:Text xml:lang="EN">Systeemmelding 6EDB::4844 XML Type error (code 19060)

Systeemmelding 6EDB::4844 XML Type error (code 19060)

Error: Systeemmelding XML Type error (6EDB::4844)
XML Type mismatch. Expected tag [http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope]Envelope, not [http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/]Envelope. Error code App:19060
Error: Systeemmelding XML Type error (6EDB::4844)
element start ("SOAP-ENV:Envelope")  rejected at 1, 240
 Error code App:19060
Generic XML Import IMPL (6EDB::11267)
Generic XML Import (6EDB::9780)</soapenv12:Text>
```

I tried various examples like: [Overwrite the Soap Envelope in Suds python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544331/overwrite-the-soap-envelope-in-suds-python)
but they all add another namespace and do not seem to work. Any suggestions would be welcome.